# first time meeting or to meet?

Tags: collocations

> Christina Mifsud is a friend Jill knows through Internet connections, and this is their first time to meet in person. [From Huffington Post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/new-life-in-florence_b_9301336)

> It was my first time meeting some of them. [From Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/ben-rimalower/scary-singing_b_1214134.html)

It's the first time I've seen a sentence in which **first time** follows a to-infinitive.
I wonder if there is any difference between the use of Ving and to infinitive here. Are they interchangeable in this case?

Comment: I (UK) don't find it at all idiomatic. I would say "this is the first time they have met in person".

Answer (score 3):

"First time meeting" is more common and natural. And works with other verbs as well:

- "This is my first time seeing an elephant in real life."
- "Is this your first time eating curry?"
- "That was his first time going to New York City."

"this is their first time to meet in person." sounds awkward and incorrect. I question the Huffington Post editor who allowed this to be printed.

As Kate said in the comments "This is the first time they have met in person" is also acceptable